# check if row exist with this kind of implementing sqlite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

how can i check a sqlite db if row exist? my style in implementing sqlite db is like this

```
public class EmployeeDBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public EmployeeDBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "registeruser.db", null, 1);

    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    //Creates Table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE register ( userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Age text, Gender text," +
                "HomeAddress text, Password text, QRID text, udpateStatus TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS register";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

for example: i want to check if there is "Name" having "john" in the sqlite db.

Comment: yes, i have done that, sorry my question is not clear, i have the SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column name]=[something], but i dont know what to do next because there are a lot of formats. should i do the cursor to get the value of it? @MarkKeen

Comment: @johnedgarotom use your statement with my answer

Comment: @MarkKeen yes it will work but can you please tell us why you don't prefer  raw query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method!

```
public boolean isRowExist(/*YOUR_INPUTS*/){
    try {
        db = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  YOUR_SEARCH_QUERY_STATMENT
         //You should use YOUR_INPUTS to create a selectQuery that can select the row/rows for you

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(c.getCount()>=1){
            c.close();
            return true;
        }
        c.close();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) to avoid having to muck around with a cursor:

```
public boolean rowExists(String table, String column, String value) {
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
            table, column+" = ?", new String[]{ value });
    return count > 0;
}
```